# javascript kendo scheduler with json data moves events only once

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, scheduler

I have a kendo scheduler and I'm having a problem with move event. I can move only one event at a time and then I can't even grab any event afterwards. I think there's something wrong with the dates but I really can't figure out why. I tried `dataSource` with 2-3 events and it's working but when I put that exact same data in php and return it as json. It's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                    date: new Date(),
                    startTime: new Date(today2()),
                    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                    currentTimeMarker: false,
                    height: 800,
                    views: 
                    [
                        "week",
                        { type: "month", selected: true, eventHeight: 60}
                    ],
                    dataSource:                 
                    {
                        transport: 
                        {
                            read:
                            {
                                url: "tasks.php",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                             batch: true,
                             parameterMap: function (options, operation)
                             {                        
                                if (operation === "read") {
                                    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

                                    var result = 
                                    {
                                        start: scheduler.view().startDate(),
                                        end: scheduler.view().endDate()
                                    }

                                    return kendo.stringify(result);
                                }

                                return kendo.stringify(options);
                            }
                        }, 
                        schema: 
                        {
                            model: 
                            {
                                id: "taskId",
                                fields: 
                                {
                                    taskId: { type: "number", from: "TT_CODE" },
                                    start: { type: "date", from: "TT_START_DATETIME"},
                                    end: { type: "date", from: "TT_END_DATETIME"},
                                    title: { from: "TT_EDIT"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        });
```

php file with json data:

```
  $json[0]['TT_CODE'] = 1;
        $json[0]['TT_START_DATETIME'] = "2016-01-16 15:00:00";
        $json[0]['TT_END_DATETIME']= "2016-01-16 16:00:00";
        $json[0]['TT_EDIT'] = "Fast and furious 6";

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Actually I understand that there is something wrong with my dates.When I have a dataSource though with data in javascript there is no problem and I think that is because of the new Date() missing. I have no problem in displaying the events though. I really can't see what is the problem with move event

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified `start` and `end` as date in your model, the scheduler is expecting to received properly formatted date. While JSON passes date as string, javascript still expect the date string to be formatted.

In your case, it would be:

```
$json[0]['TT_CODE'] = 1;
$json[0]['TT_START_DATETIME'] = "2016-01-16T15:00:00.000Z";
$json[0]['TT_END_DATETIME']= "2016-01-16T16:00:00.000Z";
$json[0]['TT_EDIT'] = "Fast and furious 6";
```

You could also leave date as is and handle the string with a custom logic in the `parameterMap` function.

As a side note, if you have a doubt about the type formatting, go in the browser console and have a look at the network tab.  You'll be able to compare the data sent by the working service to the data sent by PHP and see where is the difference.

Comment: how can I use parameterMap to format my dates like new Date('TT_START_DATETIME')?? I tried with parse like that but with no luck:
parse: 

function(response) 
       {
         var tasks = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
         {
        var task = 
        {
          id: response[i].TT_CODE,
          start: new Date(response[i].TT_START_DATETIME),
          end: new Date(response[i].TT_END_DATETIME),
          title: response[i].TT_EDIT
        }
        
        tasks.push(task);
         }
         return tasks;
       }